# Do add-in and its popup browser window share a same localStorage?

Tags: popup, local-storage, ms-office, office-js

I am building an Excel add-in with JavaScript API.

The add-in can popup a browser window by

```
popup = window.open("https://localhost:3000/#/new", "popup", "status=1, location=1, width=1000, height=1200");
```

I have tested that the add-in and the popup browser window could communicate by `postMessage`.

However, it seems that they do NOT share the same `localStorage`. For exemple, if i set `localStorage.setItem("item", "content")` in the webpage, `localStorage.getItem("item")` in the add-in returns `null`.

Does anyone know if the add-in and the popup browser window share the same localStorage?

PS: I have tested that an add-in **itself** can set an item in `localStorage` and get the value. Also, webpages can set and get items in `localStorage` even though they may be in the same browser window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They do not (on Office for Windows).  They run in different trust modes, do cookies, localStorage, etc. are ***not*** shared.

If you need a popup-like scenario, that is what the DialogAPI is for.

Comment: Will `postMessage` work between Dialog and the add-in?

Comment: No, I don't think so, for the same reason.  You will want the DialogAPI (and possibly a combination with writing to local storage and listening on the other end, to communicate between the two if you want two-way communication -- today's DialogAPI only supports dialog-to-parent but not the other way, yet)

Comment: sorry, DialogAPI is also a webpage, right? If an add-in can communicate with a popup window by `postMessage` (even for cross-domain), why an add-in cannot communicate with its Dialog via `postMessage`, unless you set some restrictions...

Comment: The communication wouldn't be through postmessage directly.  It would be through the API, which proxies the communication.

Answer (score -1):

I think you could use something like SignalR to communicate between the two, if you're working in asp.net.  If you are working in a different environment like node a standard websocket approach should work.